# What is an overriding declaration in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am getting an error, “Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword” in my init, but I don't understand what declaration I am overriding. Or even what, in simple terms, a declaration is.

```
class MyViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var coolName: String = "”
    @Published var coolLocation: String = "”
    @Published private(set) var results: Array<AddressResult> = []
    @Published var searchableText = "”
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @Published private(set) var annotationItems: [AnnotationItem] = []
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private lazy var localSearchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleter = {
        let completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
        completer.delegate = self
        return completer
    }()
    
    init() {
        observeSearchableText()
    }
    
    func observeSearchableText() {
        $searchableText
            .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] recievedValue in
                self?.searchAddress(recievedValue)
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "inherit" from `NSObject` you have to `override` its initializer

```
class Somthing: NSObject{
    override init() {
        //You should also call the super class' initializer.
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So, you override NSObject first and then initialize NSObject within your init?  Is that what is happening here?

Comment: @mystride yes, creating a specific one and then initializing the parent.